# Using RewriteCond and RewriteRule to redirect one page

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, redirect

When a user navigates to http://mydomain.nl/nl/my-page/

I need the user to be redirected to http://mydomain.nl/fnl/my-page/

This is because the website I'm working on is a multi-store multi-language Magento webshop which was wrongly configured by someone before me, so that each language has its own store scopes rather than each store having its on language scopes.

I have the following code in my .htaccess :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/nl/terms-and-conditions-of-use/ http://mydomain.nl/fnl/terms-and-conditions-of-use/ [NC,QSA,R]
```

Basically, what I assume this does is check that it's on the proper domain (that being mydomain.nl) then redirecting the URL so that the user see's the proper page.

The redirect isn't working. If I click on it - it takes me back to the home page of the main domain (that then being anotherdomain.nl)

Could someone take a look at it and see what I'm doing wrong?

-EDIT-

There is one Magento install installed on adomain.nl - there are multiple stores set up with different domains pointing to them. So mydomain.nl is technically adomain.nl/mydomain as a second store in Magento itself. I want to point mydomain.nl/nl/*anything* towards mydomain.nl/fnl/*whichever page was requested*. In the .htaccess I need to specify that I only want this to be done on mydomain.nl and not a domain.nl

I hope this clears things up - it's quite complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though anubhava's answer is similiar this worked for me:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^nl/terms-and-conditions-of-use/ /fnl/terms-and-conditions-of-use/ [NC,L,R]
```

Simply redirects anyone who visits http://domain.nl/nl/terms-and-conditions-of-use/ to http://domain.nl/fnl/terms-and-conditions-of-use and it only does this when the user goes to domain.nl - useful for Magento multi-store sites using only one .htaccess file.

Comment: This is pretty much same as my answer. One should add an answer only when existing answers aren't good enough OR else if they don't cover certain aspects of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Remove leading slash:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?adomain\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^nl/(terms-and-conditions-of-use)/ /fnl/$1/ [NC,L,R]
```

Or making it **more generic:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?adomain\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^nl/(.+) /fnl/$1 [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: I have tried both ways but neither seem to be working.. does it matter where in the .htaccess file I place the code?

Comment: With both options it seems to redirect to mydomain.nl now instead of anotherdomain.nl - so it is doing something. Still doesn't display the proper page. RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^funcookshop\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^nl/terms-and-conditions-of-use/ /fnl/terms-and-conditions-of-use/ [NC,L,R]

Comment: `anotherdomain.nl`? But you original rule didn't have it. Let me edit the answer.

Comment: Sorry I may have misinformed you slightly -> check the edit under my answer for a more detailed explanation on what I'm trying to achieve. It's quite confusing for me but this is just the way someone else set up the multi-site.